# C# Convert Date From Begining of Time To DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, oledb

Ok I am reading a excel sheet using a OLEDB connection. When the Values are formatted like:

```
40909   41274
```

These are always 365 apart so i know there has to be a correlation between these and DateTime DataType. I have tried multiple things off Google and keep getting format exceptions.

What is the easiest way to convert these to a simple MM/DD/YYYY value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.FromOADate(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx) which *"Returns a DateTime equivalent to the specified OLE Automation Date."*

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(40909));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(41274));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

How the number is calculated is it is the number of days from `12/30/1899` with the time of the day represented as the decimal portion of the number. For example midnight would be `.0` and noon would be `.5`.

Dates before `12/30/1899` are represented by negative numbers.